# Can a master Bluetooth device use more than one antenna to connect to slaves?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm not sure how to correctly phrase this question, as I'm just starting to learn Bluetooth and its ways, but... imagine holding in an iPhone or Android phone in your hand in a large building with many rooms. You pair your device with a Bluetooth master device via an antenna in that room. Then once you move from room to room, your device communicates with other antennas throughout the building, but the device treats it as one pairing.

- Is this at all possible? Was Bluetooth developed with this in mind at all?
- Would this still work if the antennas were wireless? My idea is for devices to communicate with nodes via Bluetooth, and nodes interact with central base via wi-fi/local router.
- Also, third random question: how does using BLE affect any of this?

Please tell me if I'm crazy! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth 4.0 BLE allows for a slave to connect to one master.  4.1 BLE allows for more than one connection, but I don't know if anything implements that yet.

Either way, there's no sort of "roaming" method pairing devices like with wifi access points with the same SSID.  BLE however doesn't require pairing like regular Bluetooth, so you could just connect to a new access point each time you lose a connection.

You can also communicate via advertising packets from the "antenna" in each room.  This would facilitate information being passed from those rooms to the phone, but not the other way around.  This is basically how you communicate with BLE when you don't pair/connect devices and is how iBeacons work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing the software yourself, and installing it in the building and on the phone, then I think it should be totally possible. Bluetooth devices can detect the distance and direction of other bluetooth devices. So if both devices are running software that is designed to, and grants permission to do so, it should be no-big-deal to programmatically auto-reconnect to the new nearest antenna whenever one becomes significantly closer than the one that your phone is currently connected to. As for software that already does this that you wouldn't have to develop from scratch yourself, no idea.